# replmiss from metafor doesn't work - still have NAs

Tags: r, missing-data, metafor

I'm trying to conduct a meta-analysis with some missing data following this example:
http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:assembling_data_smd?s[]=difference&s[]=means

but the replmiss command doesn't work for me and I'm left with NAs so the studies with the missing values are omitted from the meta-analysis.

The only difference I can find between the example in the link and what I'm doing is that I, naturally, have the NAs before I create the tval, dval and pval variables and in the link they first create them and then insert NAs.

This is my data:

```
dat2 = data.frame(
  source = c("1_p","3_f","5_y","6_t","7_k","9_l","15_h"),
  m1i = c(3,11,15,6,9,11,10),
  sd1i = c(NA, NA, 4, NA, 2, 2, NA),
  m2i = c(4,12,15,13,11,12,9),
  sd2i = c(NA, NA,4 ,NA,5,3,NA),
  n1i = c(36, 49, 30, 30, 84, 66, 20),
  n2i = c(37, 42, 30, 30, 80, 68, 28)
  )
```

Anyone has good experience with replmiss and know how to make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what is happening in that example. It shows how one can compute the d-values from *other* information besides the means and SDs if the latter is not provided. Your `dat2` data frame does not contain anything besides means and SDs and since some of those are missing, the resulting d-values will be missing.

Comment: Thanks! I added the p-value data I had for some of the studies and it worked.